# Why I am unable to animate DecorView

Tags: android

I have this code

```
    private void animateView(View view) {
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0,
                90, 180, 270, 360);
        animator.setDuration(5000);
        animator.setRepeatCount(10);
        animator.start();
    }
```

and when I am passing a `View` that is returned by `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);`, I can see the animation. but when I am passing DecorView i.e. the `View` that is returned by `getWindow().getDecorView()`, DecorView is not getting animated...

Comment: I tested your code and I am getting an animation with getWindow().getDecorView(). All the layout is being animated. Which API version device are you testing your code?

Comment: @joao2fast4u It's API 16...

Comment: me too and it is working. Where are you calling that method?

Comment: @joao2fast4u calling after 5 seconds using Handler in onResume()...

Comment: Did you try it without the Handler? Could you show the Handler code, please?

Comment: Try to run the code in a emulator or another device.

Comment: animating the decor view on 4.0.4 is not working. works on, at least, 5.1, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate DecorView. If you want to animate the whole window(including ActionBar), you can use this code:

animateView((View)(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent()));

May this can help you.